# Fast method to get current time with nsec-resolution?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel-module

I try to get a time-information with a resolution of a few hundred nanoseconds (to do some bit-banging stuff on an Raspberry Pi). I tried with clock_gettime() which provides the required resolution in timespec.tv_nsec, but it is too slow. Even when I run my process on one separate core of the CPU exclusively and even when I set this process to highest priority, the whole time measurement loop needs about 450 nsec where about 360 nsec are used by the function clock_gettime().

So my question: is there a way to faster retrieve the current time? Any other time-function? Or would it be a solution to use a kernel-module instead of a user space process?

Comment: This may be of interest - see section entitled *"Getting Direct Ticks"* http://yosh.ke.mu/article/raspberry_pi_getting_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. `clock_gettime()` is already implemented through the vDSO, so it's likely to be the fastest possible system call there is.

But consider the timescales involved. With a 2 GHz processor, 450 nanoseconds is only 900 clock cycles. That's not very much.

On one 1,86 GHz Core 2 machine, running just `clock_gettime()` in a loop returns values that are 86 ns apart. Just adding a filler of `for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++);` increases that to 540 ns. (about 4,5 ns per loop iteration, or around 8-9 clock cycles)

There's not much you can you do in that time. What you can do, is to count clock cycles, or loop iterations. Use `clock_gettime()` beforehand to determine how much time a busyloop of *N* iterations requires on that machine, and then scale the number of iterations to get a timing loop of a required length.

You're probably still going to need some time when doing the actual bit-flipping, assuming it goes through a system call. A kernel module might be useful there, in that you could avoid the system call overhead. Inside the kernel, it might also be easier to prevent the code from being pre-empted while working on the bit-banging.